# Laravel search with multiple `where`s

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to do a search using `where` in po website.

My code:

```
public function globalSearch($subject) {
    $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->get();
    $users = User::where('steam_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->get();

    $results = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $results[$user->username] = url('player/'.$user->slug);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

But it's only searching for steam_id and if I put username it does not find anything. I think the problem is, that I need to use multiple `where`s in 1 line. Sorry if you don't understand what I mean but how can I use 1 `where` with multiple fields?

Comment: You're overwriting `$users` with that second statement. Do you want an OR or an AND where?

Answer (score 1):

Below two lines are overriding your search.So remove that two lines and write it as below.

```
 $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->get();
 $users = User::where('steam_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->get();
```

User below code.

```
 $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->orwhere('steam_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `$users` with that second statement. If you want a result with both `where` clauses, you can use an array as options:

```
$users = User::where([
    ['username', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%'],
    ['steam_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%']
])->get();
```

More on [Laravel where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses).

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the job?

```
public function globalSearch($subject)
{
  return User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->orWhere('steam_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$subject.'%')->get();
}
```

Ideally group by the table index to not get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an array inside of the `User::where()` like @kerbholz answers states correctly. Or you can go for a chaining like so:

```
User::where('foo', 1)->where('bar', false)->get();
```

Which will result in the same result as the answer above but in my opinion is usually more readable.